# Como usar variables de un metodo ActionListener en otra clase

Tags: java, variables, jtextfield, jbutton

Tengo creada una ventana de presentación para un simulador, en el panel inferior tengo 2 JTextField y un JButton para guardar lo que el usuario ingrese en los JTextField, los cuales solo serán números y solo admiten 2 dígitos cada uno. Ya tengo implementado todo esto, guardo lo ingresado en 2 variables distintas:

```
public void jButtonGuardaDatos(ActionEvent e){
    jButtonGuarda.addActionListener(this);
    int recoger2 = Integer.parseInt(jTextColumnas.getText());
    int recoger = Integer.parseInt(jTextFilas.getText());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Las filas " + recoger + " y las columnas " + recoger2);//verificar si funciona
}
```

**JButtonGuarda** es el boton para guardarlos,
**JTextColumnas** y **JTextFilas** son los campos de texto,
**recoger** y **recoger2** son las variables donde guardo lo ingresado.

**Lo que necesito es poder sacar las variables del método para poder usarlas fuera de el y ademas fuera de la clase**, pero no encuentro manera de hacerlo.
Agradecería si alguien pudiese ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es realmente fácil, solo tienes que crear las variables que vas a guardar fuera del método, luego solo le estableces el valor que quieras, puedes crear un método getter para obtener el valor de esa variable desde otra clase

```
private int recoger1;
private int recoger2;

public static int getRecoger1(){ 
  return recoger1;
}

public static int getRecoger2(){
  return recoger2;
}

public void jButtonGuardaDatos(ActionEvent e){
    jButtonGuarda.addActionListener(this);
    recoger1 = Integer.parseInt(jTextFilas.getText());
    recoger2 = Integer.parseInt(jTextColumnas.getText());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Las filas " + recoger1 + " y las columnas " + recoger2);//verificar si funciona
}
```

Luego en otra clase para obtener el valor guardado en esas variables solo tienes que llamar a los getters creados en esa clase, supongamos que la clase con los getters se llama "Tabla" y quieres obtener los valores desde la clase "Imprimir", ejemplo:

```
System.out.println("Las filas son: " + Tabla.getRecoger1() + " y las columnas: " + Tabla.getRecoger2());
```

Llamas a Tabla (nombre de la calse) .getRecoger1() (el valor de la variable), de esta forma si la variable es estática, si no primero tendrías que crear un objeto y llamar a esta variable con el getter, espero haberte ayudado, lo escribí sin probarlo, pero de este modo se consigue...

Te recomiendo aprender mas de programación orientada a objetos, ahí mismo esta la respuesta de pasar información de una clase a otra. :)

Comment: hola gracias por tu respuesta, funciona pero no como deseo, ya que me retorna 0, la clase que tengo se llama veentana la cual tiene un constructor en el cual se inicia un metodo llamado initComponents para agregar los componentes a la ventana y ahi dentro esta el metodo para capturar los jtextfield JButtonGuardaDatos entonces al llamarle de otra clase esta me pide que cree el metodo fuera de initComponents pero solo retorna 0